# Error in parsing date

Tags: java, date

I have the following code. The problem occurs when getting the month. It says 'The 'month' argument must be in the range 1 to 12.' and it always return 0. Why?

```
    String target = "2013-01-04";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = df.parse(target);

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(date);
   int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   System.out.println("year-"+year);
   int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   System.out.println("month-"+month);
   int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   System.out.println("day-"+day);
```

Comment: read the javadoc...month is 0-based (i.e. January=0 and December=11).

Comment: ok thanks. so i should add +1 everytime.

Comment: if you really want to..i'm not the one writing the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quirk of the Calendar class. For some insane reason, it uses a zero-based index for months, even though all other date parts are one-based.

Don't even think about raising an issue about this, as you'll join a long line of people: Calendar is arguably the most broken class in the JDK.

The "fix" is to use the [jodatime library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net), which is great for all your date manipulation, parsing and formatting needs. It's practically the industry standard now.